# How to auto expand Enter as a single change?

Tags: key-bindings

I want to implement a <kbd>Enter</kbd> expansion for [my plugin](https://github.com/purpleP/smartpairs.git) like [delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate) and [auto pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) do.

I've done `inoremap <CR> <CR><C-o>O`, but If I want to undo what seems like a single change I would need obviously undo twice.

How to do that as a single change?

By <kbd>Enter</kbd> expansion I mean this:

```
some(|)

Pressing enter

some(
    |
)
```

Comment: Seems to work out of the box on the latest Vim. But check out [this vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-repeatable-mappings-with-repeat-vim/) about [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat).

Comment: @LEI what seems to work out of the box? Latest vim expands <CR>?

Comment: When I set the mapping and use it with `vim -u NONE`, I don't need to undo twice to get back to the original state.

Comment: How have you tested it? Vim doesn't insert tab automatically with `-u NONE`. Not sure how to switch it.

Comment: @LEI I've updated my question. It's standard name, `delimitMate` names it so and so does `AutoPairs`

Comment: cannot reproduce using `vim -u NONE -N  -c ':set cindent' -c 'inoremap <cr> <cr><c-o>O'` then inserting `some()`, putting the cursor in insert mode between the parenthesis in insert mode and pressing enter.  This will correctly indent and be undoable with one single step.